# Why am I getting NameError: 'Wolf' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, module

I just edited below to simplify, and update my problems status.

I have made a simple enemy class called 'Wolf'. Before I pulled this text out into a new file, my main file ran with no errors.

IF I TRY TO IMPORT ONLY WOLF:

```
from Enemy Import Wolf
```

I get the following:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Wolf' from 'Enemy'

Below are all of my files.

When I run my main program, the game runs but crashes when I close it and gives me an error.

**Enemy.py**

```
import pygame
import random
import Colors

    
class Wolf(pygame.sprite.Sprite):    
        def __init__(self, color, width, height):
            super().__init__()
            self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
            self.image.fill(color)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

**Main_Game_File.py**

```
import pygame
import random
import Colors
import Player
import Enemy
        
# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width  = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

#SPRITE LIST CREATIONS
wolf_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
poison_wolf_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
# This is a list of every sprite. 
# All blocks and the player block as well.
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
 
for i in range(50):
    # This represents a single block
    wolf = Wolf(Colors.GREEN, 20, 15)
    # Set a random location for the block
    wolf.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    wolf.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height)
    # Add the block to the list of objects
    wolf_list.add(wolf)
    all_sprites_list.add(wolf)
    
for i in range(50):
    # This represents a single block
    wolf = Wolf(Colors.RED, 20, 15)
    # Set a random location for the block
    wolf.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    wolf.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height)
    # Add the block to the list of objects
    poison_wolf_list.add(wolf)
    all_sprites_list.add(wolf)
    #Since this will repeat 50 times, you will create 50 red blocks
    #This adds all 50 blocks to the bad_block_list, and the all_sprites_list.
 
# Create a RED player block
player = Player.Player(100, 100)
all_sprites_list.add(player)
 
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
 
# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
score = 0
 
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True

        # Set the speed based on the key pressed
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
 
        # Reset speed when key goes up
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(Colors.WHITE)
 
    # Game Logic
    all_sprites_list.update()

 
    # See if the player block has collided with anything.
    wolf_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, wolf_list, True)
    poison_wolf_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, poison_wolf_list, True)
    # Check the list of collisions.
    for block in wolf_list:
        score += 1
        print(score)
    for block in poison_wolf_list:
        score -= 1
        print(score) 
    # Draw all the spites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
 
    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
 
    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)
 
pygame.quit()
```

**Player.py**

```
import pygame
import random
import Colors

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ The class is the player-controlled sprite. """
 
    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Constructor function"""
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(Colors.BLUE)
 
        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
 
        # -- Attributes
        # Set speed vector
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
 
    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        """ Change the speed of the player"""
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y
 
    def update(self):
        """ Find a new position for the player"""
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
```

**Colors**

```
# Colors
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 225,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 225)
```

Comment: As i said, i tried that. The error changed to say AttributeError: module 'Enemy' has no attribute 'Wolf'

Comment: @JoshStapley Then you have a problem in your Enemy module, because it does evidently does not define Wolf as you think it does.

Comment: What I posted was the entire module. When the class Wolf(): was posted into the main code, it worked smooth.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.  Expecting us to eye-check partial code is not a tenable practice.

Comment: Ok i edited the post to show all the files needed to run the program. Thanks for looking at this guys. Sorry for not posting it earlier! i was trying to simplify for you haha

Comment: I put your code into files. I replaced `Wolf` with `Enemy.Wolf`. And the error was solved. Using `Enemy.Wolf` is the correct solution, and if it doesn't work for you, there's something wrong about the information you're giving us.

Comment: A suggestion: put `print(Enemy)` in your code after you import it, and make sure that it indicates the file that you intended. Because your descriptions indicate that `Enemy.py` does *not* contain what you say it contains.

Comment: So i just edited my original post, thanks everybody for helping me with this. It means a lot. @khelwood I tried to print Wolf and it didn't work, so i tried what you said again and prefixed all the calls to wolf with Enemy. It didn't work in my file, but I found i may have a different problem. 

If i type "from Enemy import Wolf". I get an error saying cannot import name 'Wolf' from Enemy. So for some reason Wolf is not being imported at all.

Comment: I didn't tell you to print Wolf. Put `print(Enemy)` in your code after you `import Enemy`. Check that the file it says is the file you think it is supposed to be. And make sure the file that it says contains the content you think it does.

Comment: I did and get the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\echob\Documents\Python\Python 3\pygames\Games\Getting Lost\Main_Game_File.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Enemy import Wolf
ImportError: cannot import name 'Wolf' from 'Enemy' (C:\Users\echob\Documents\Python\Python 3\pygames\Games\Getting Lost\Enemy.py)

Comment: Hey, turns out somehow my Enemy File didn't save when i thought it did, so it was trying to run an empty file named Enemy. Thanks guys! figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Main_Game_File.py lines 91/92, you're overwriting the Groups with lists.

Use Enemy.Wolf for the imports and change those lines.

```
    wolf_list_2 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, wolf_list, True)
    poison_wolf_list_2 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, poison_wolf_list, True)
    # Check the list of collisions.
    for block in wolf_list_2:
        score += 1
        print(score)
    for block in poison_wolf_list_2:
        score -= 1
        print(score)
        # Draw all the spites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch! This didn't fix my problem, but you were right that certainly was a mistake as it messed with how i kept score.

Comment: That fix and using Enemy.Wolf, the game runs perfect for me. It must be something with your environment configuration. It's a cool game so far too, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to prefix it with the module import name.

```
import Enemy
        
# [...]

mr_wolf = Enemy.Wolf(Colors.GREEN, 20, 15)   # <-- HERE
```

Or use the `import *` notation:

```
from Enemy import *                    # <-- HERE
        
# [...]

mr_wolf = Wolf(Colors.GREEN, 20, 15)   # (no change)
```

How modules are imported changes the naming scope.

Or of course, you can import *only* `Wolf` from `Enemy` too:

```
from Enemy import Wolf                 # <-- HERE
        
# [...]

mr_wolf = Wolf(Colors.GREEN, 20, 15)   # (no change)
```

**EDIT: Example files:**

`Enemy.py` ~

```
import pygame

class Wolf(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def __str__( self ):
        return "Wolf at (%d,%d) size %dx%d" % ( self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.rect.width, self.rect.height )
```

`main.py` ~

```
import Enemy

YELLOW = ( 255, 255, 0 )

mr_wolf = Enemy.Wolf( YELLOW, 10, 10)

print( str( mr_wolf ) )
```

Which gives:

```
# python3 ./main.py
pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Wolf at (0,0) size 10x10
```

Comment: I actually did try both of those options, but as stated above, the error code changed to:
    wolf = Enemy.Wolf(Colors.GREEN, 20, 15)
AttributeError: module 'Enemy' has no attribute 'Wolf'

Comment: Ok i just tried importing only 'Wolf', and got a whole new error. It says:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Wolf' from 'Enemy'

Comment: @JoshStapley - Are you sure it's defined exactly like your question then?  I'll edit my answer to include an example.

Comment: Thanks for coming back, I figured it out. I made a huge noob error. I hadn't saved my Enemy.py, since i added the wolf class. I just kept saving and running the main file while editing the Enemy file.